# Multiple Regression : Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r

I am a rookie to R. I am trying to run multiple regression on Boston Housing DataSet. I have successfully built a Multiple Regression Model but when I am trying to run the same model on Test Data, I am getting the error

> Multiple Regression : Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not
>   found

My data set has the following columns:

> CRIM,ZN,INDUS,CHAS,NOX,RM,AGE,DIS,RAD,TAX,PTRATIO,B,LSTAT

I am trying to predict the value of column

> MEDV

The snippet of my code is as follows:

```
file.exists("Boston.xlsx")
require(readxl)
Boston = read_excel("Boston.xlsx", sheet = "Data")
head(Boston,2)
nr <- round(0.5*nrow(Boston))
Boston_training <- Boston[1:nr, ]
Boston_training
test_start <- nr+1
test_end <- nrow(Boston)
Boston_testing <- Boston[test_start:test_end, ]
Boston_testing

RegModel.train2 <- lm(MEDV~CRIM+ZN+INDUS+CHAS+NOX+RM+AGE+DIS+RAD+TAX+PTRATIO+B+LSTAT,data=Boston_training)
require(car)
vif(RegModel.train2)
predictedValues <-predict(RegModel.train2, data.frame(Boston_testing$MEDV))
actualValues <-data.frame(testing$medv)
```

My training data set is Boston_Training and test data set is Boston_testing
I am constantly getting the error:-

```
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'CRIM' not found"
```

Not able to find a workaround this. Have scraped through almost all the questions.

Comment: Use `predictedValues <-predict(RegModel.train2, Boston_testing)`.

Comment: Did anybody get a solution for this? I am trying this from ISLR and doing the similar steps after taking out a few predictors. `crim` is still one  of the predictors. I don't know why its not found.